# Kalman filter of opencv doesnt work in ROS

Tags: c++, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, im trying to adapt a Kalman filter cpp code to a node cpp in ROS, but in the very beginning, the initialization goes wrong, more precisly, when i try to set  the matrices, this is the relevant part of the code.

```
int stateSize = 4;
int measSize = 2;
int contrSize = 0;
unsigned int type = CV_32F;
cv::KalmanFilter kf(stateSize, measSize, contrSize, type);
cv::Mat state(stateSize, 1, type);  // [x,y,v_x,v_y,w,h]
cv::Mat meas(measSize, 1, type);
setIdentity(kf.measurementMatrix);
```

The compiler shows me the next error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
setIdentity(kf.measurementMatrix);
```

I really have no idea what is happening, because those lines show no problem in the "pure" cpp code.
Hope someone can help me, thanks.

EDIT 1:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include <ros/package.h>
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <geometry_msgs/Point.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213081/kalman-filter-of-opencv-doesnt-work-in-ros/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is `setIdentity` defined? It looks like the compiler can't find it. Can you do something like this instead?

```
kf.measurementMatrix = Mat::eye(kf.measurementMatrix.rows, kf.measurementMatrix.cols, CV_64F);
```

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-07-08**:
I tried your solution, but it shows me the next error:

```
error: ‘kf’ does not name a type
```

kf.measurementMatrix = Mat::eye(kf.measurementMatrix.rows, kf.measurementMatrix.cols, CV_64F);
^
setIdentity is defined in opencv operations.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-07-08**:
Sorry, I didn't mean that you should only use that line of code. Just replace the line where you were calling `setIdentity` with the line I gave you. You declared `kf` in the line just before it.

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-07-08**:
Yeah thats what I have done. I didnt delete the KalmanFilter kf linea, but it showed me that

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-07-08**:
What do your includes look like?

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-07-12**:
The include is in the question, dont know why the format crushed

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-12**:\

> dont know why the format crushed

Because you didn't use the *Preformatted text* toolbar button to format it properly (it's the ony with `101010` on it).